# Darf ich meinen Fragebogen hier verlinken oder verstößt das gegen die Regeln?

Tags: discussion

Ich suche noch Teilnehmer, die mich bei meiner Masterarbeit unterstützen, und wollte daher fragen, ob ich meinen Fragebogen auch hier verlinken darf?

Ich studiere Finance und es geht, um das Verhalten von Investoren, wobei jedoch jeder am Fragenbogen teilnehmen kann.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auf der Hauptseite kannst Du nur nach allgemeingültigen Informationen fragen, mal ganz abgesehen davon, dass Deine Umfrage nichts mit der deutschen Sprache zu tun haben scheint. Ankündigungen sind auf Meta zwar zulässig, aber dann müssen sie besondere Relevanz für die Nutzerschaft dieser Seite haben.

Wenn Du also eine Umfrage hättest, die sich explizit an die Nutzerschaft dieser Seite richten würde, wäre das eventuell in Ordnung. (Bitte aber dennoch vorher nochmal nachfragen.)